# How to prevent Spring validation on update

Tags: spring, validation, annotations

I made a custom validation annotation for unique email (When user registers itself, program checks if email is already in database).

Everything works just fine, but when I need to modify user's info and not to create a new one I run into a problem that says "Email is already in use"

Can I somehow turn off only `@UniqueEmail` validation(I need the others like email pattern and password validation)?

All validation annotations are in the same User bean.

Thank You.

Comment: Don't turn it off, fix your validation instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you are using `javax.validation`.

First you need an `interface OnUpdate`:

```
javax.validation.groups.Default

public interface OnUpdate extends Default {}
```

Now you need to set *all* the annotations that need to **only** run on `UPDATE`:

```
@NotNull(groups = OnUpdate.class)
```

Now, you have divided your validations into two groups, those in `OnUpdate` and those in `Default`. Running `Default` will include those in `OnUpdate` as `OnUpdate` extends `Default`.

Now, this is where it gets a little tricky - you need to tell the framework which validations to run on each task.

If using JPA you just need to set the following property:

```
javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update = com.my.package.OnUpdate
```

Comment: Jep thanx! This worked for me! Tried to fix it couple different ways, but this one is the easiest and more elegant :D

Comment: With Spring Boot 2.0.4 the property `javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update` was not recognized nor necessary. Instead annotate the controller method's parameter with @Validated({OnUpdate.class}), only in the method where you need your custom validation.

Comment: @PacoAbato that is incorrect. This answer is about triggering JPA validation. Your comment is about validating incoming requests in Spring MVC. This is very different.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh, sorry, I mixed concepts that I don't understand yet. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: why is it not throwing a bad request like other validations and instead is throwing 500?

Comment: @ancm because this validation is at the persistence layer not the mvc layer. If you want to handle it in some way, you’ll need to add that yourself. If you want validation at the mvc layer, then don’t use this method.

Answer (score 0):

Further to Boris The Spider's answer, if you want to do this in code rather than with persistence.xml you can create the following bean:

```
  @Bean
  public HibernatePropertiesCustomizer hibernatePropertiesCustomizer(final Validator validator) {
    return new HibernatePropertiesCustomizer() {

      @Override
      public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class[] classes = {OnUpdate.class};
        hibernateProperties.put("javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update", classes);
      }
    };
  }
```