# Micronaut - different validation for different operations

Tags: java, validation, constraints, micronaut

I have an JavaDTO like:

```
public class myDTO {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;
}
```

I want to do **different validation** in Micronaut by an **CREATE operation** and by an **UPDATE operation**. In *Spring* you can define different 'groups' therefore. See here [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36567917/how-to-prevent-spring-validation-on-update)  or here [external link](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/#using-validation-groups-to-validate-objects-differently-for-different-use-cases). So this looks like:

```
public class myDTO {
    @Null(groups = OnCreate.class)
    @NotNull(groups = OnUpdate.class)
    private String name;

    @Null(groups = OnCreate.class)
    @NotNull(groups = OnUpdate.class)
    private Integer age;
}
```

Is there something similiar for micronaut there?

Comment: Is your question specific to Micronaut Data?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Yes, I am using Micronaut. As you can see in the links, Spring provides therefore a functionality. For Micronaut i didn't find anything for this. Also, I think it is more a 'core' functionality instead of 'data'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not Spring functionality but more how beans are validated from the `javax` bean validator.

You need to use Hibernate Validator where `javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update` are applicable.

Default Micronaut bean validation is not using Hibernate Validator.
Try to add hibernate validator as dependency.

https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-hibernate-validator/latest/guide/index.html